# Mono Entity Framework 6 Duplicates

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mono

I'm using a Entity Framework 6 implementation on my Windows computer and it's working fine. In order to use on a Linux computer I tried to run the project using Mono. When the program tries to access EF6 I receive the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The configured column orders for the table 'Table' contains duplicates. Ensure the specified column order values are distinct.
  at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.ColumnOrderingConventionStrict.ValidateColumns (System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityType table, System.String tableName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.ColumnOrderingConvention.Apply (System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityType item, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbModel model) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: We are having problems with EF 6 running on Mono too. Hopefully someone knows the answer.

Comment: Hello Erik, which version of EF, Mono, MySQL are you using?

Comment: MySQL 5.5.35 and the latest version of Mono (3.2.7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution. Some of my entities were using the attribute Column. In my case I was using `[Column(TypeName = "Date")]`. When I have removed this attribute, I was able to run the entity framework on my Linux server.

Comment: That's not really a solution when the `Column` attribute is required.  For example, I _need_ to specify that the column type is `datetime2`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the EF Fluent API instead of the [Column] attribute worked for me:

modelBuilder.Entity().Property(t => t.SomeProp).HasColumnType("mytype");

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is quite old, but anyways, I ended up here.

Using EF Code First, I added a column in my model and changed the table class manually.

Check if there is no duplicates. You can fix it by changing the `[Column(Order = 1)]`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error for Entity Framework 6 Code First for this model:

```
public class CycleTest
{
    [MaxLength(5)]
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string Action { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Cycle { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Case"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public string BusinessSystemId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Case"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CaseId { get; set; }

    public virtual Case Case { get; set; }
}
```

Changed the Column values for `ForeignKey` properties and then everything worked. Like this:

```
public class CycleTest
{
    [MaxLength(5)]
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string Action { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Cycle { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Case"), Column(Order = 2)]
    public string BusinessSystemId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Case"), Column(Order = 3)]
    public int CaseId { get; set; }

    public virtual Case Case { get; set; }
}
```